# MailChimp emails broken on pasted code but not on saved template?

Tags: html, email, outlook, gmail, mailchimp

I have a custom coded mailchimp template. If I create and send a campaign by "pasting your own code" the emails appear visually broken in gmail. If I create and send a campaign using a saved template, the emails in gmail are fine.

The code is EXACTLY the same in both cases.

Emails always appear to be fine in Outlook and "view in browser" versions.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have been an issue with gmail needing "inline styling". probably due to head being cut out by gmail so none of the styles were being applied.

Mailchimp has an option for this when you copy paste code under the "settings" tab.